# Decrypt AES-256 file with given key in OpenSSL or Python

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

This is my first question here at Stack Overflow. Sorry if I make some mistakes.
I'm trying to decrypt a file which is encrypted in AES 256, and I discovered the key doing other process my activity demanded. The file has this fragment:

```
U2FsdGVkX18GOEOW9JWvz65r1bWsle2dMwO6nV11mW0APl8Jz+AZ1bwi7V9Ykxr8
lbUr2PJ6IXd5nRcbq0rivMJpZTB6RQOwupTAPmAlFr98PbIQUIszaA+BTjYsWq3Q
pYqAJ4BVqqY39H0EhXsuKwMv4tcolzWfEajAuHqVUbks/EqWA7H6v1B9jH/5EzYf
scLVm+L+YOI3R2ARwegt5b6sPaIID92k7ioM7iRjM09Ycxrs9EvJVsXdOCLWDvGt
//and more characters...
```

and the key I discovered is:

```
6AYwFJffIFVVpYkCUFf4Jw==
```

I've tryed some solutions using PyCrypto and OpenSSL without success. Some algorithms I found in Python needed IV, and I just have the key, and this key is in a particular format I don't know what is. I found some commands in OpenSSL but I couldn't decrypt, some messages showed up like "bad magic number" or "deprecated key derivation used". This is an example of command:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -nosalt -md sha256 -pass file:keycipher.pem -in ciphertext.enc -out message.txt
```

*--Additional information--*

This is part of a work given by my professor at university. He gave us 3 files: the AES 256 encrypted message file, the key (but encrypted in RSA), and a public RSA key. I've found the private RSA key and then applied this command:

```
openssl rsault -decrypt -inkey private.pem -in key.cipher -out aeskey.txt
```

The RSA private key I used is

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIHBAgEAAiYOWxON4VVOCjgECz38THnFRTqJY2gENjwnu266/sg0yYw6BiggVQID
AQABAiYKAICuQInrtojyoFaOm0XYIPS4gdMeNj3C5uWo2IfKGNERZ8+4AQITPX2s
M0jDhgm4ndB+ijBfokJuAQITO8QkAkcydrUiO+qEJlMfWe2aVQITFVxIq3AFa9SI
q1m3+20ea5FEAQITL1bOxtcqC4ixkw/QmKKiZJKk+QITA+HQAN0Pyy+LQVUdHZPk
Xcku+Q==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The key.cipher file is a binary or something I don't know, because when you open, it shows:

```
lŽŽ?Ež±ÄtÇÅÆžCx€(AÃEÇåÞ5³LÍŒðEïS
//hex now
03 6C B4 B4 3F 45 B8 B1 C4 74 C7 C5 C6 9E B8 43 13 78 A4 28 41 C3 45 C7 E5 
DE 13 35 B3 4C 9E CD 8A BC F0 45 EF 53
```

And then the AES key appeared for me. I'm stuck in this part now, how to decrypt the message with the key I found. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sometimes the IV is simply prefixed to the ciphertext (i.e. the first 16 bytes after decoding). Which modes of operation have you tried? Have you tried an all-zero IV already? Note that a password is not a key, try the `-K` option without `-md` and `-pass` options.

Comment: I don't know the suitable command to do that (all-zero IV). And I don't know how to insert the key I found in Python, if it's just open file or something else. Ok, I'll try the flags you said.
When I use `-K` and the key, it says "Extra arguments given"

Comment: Based on your provided information, I'm almost sure that you have calculated key incorrectly. it is 16 bytes long, but if AES-256 was used, it should be 32 bytes long. You have calculated key incorrectly or it is not AES-256. In addition, why you assume that encryption mode is CBC? Please add original `private.pem` and `key.cipher` too.

Comment: I'm very confused. How do I know the lenght of the key? I will add in the question the private.pem

Comment: @RodrigoRaupp the key that you posted(`6AYwFJffIFVVpYkCUFf4Jw==`) is obviously base64 encoded. if you decrypt it(or just approximate with length*0.75) you notice it is 16 bytes long. For `key.cipher`, open it in  a hex editor and post hex bytes.

Comment: I updated with the hex bytes